# Change the default page color on a window 8 store application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When I create a new page on a windows 8 store application it has default color which I want to change. If I remove all elements on the page and change the background color it has no effect. I've set the back ground to pink in my example below. How can I make this color take effect? (I've also removed everything out of App.xaml)

```xml
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="DemoWindows8StoreApp.BasicPage3"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DemoWindows8StoreApp"
xmlns:common="using:DemoWindows8StoreApp.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Background="Pink"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**

According to [`Control.Background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.background.aspx)

> Each control might apply this property differently based on its visual
>   template. This property only affects a control whose template uses the
>   Background property as a parameter. On other controls, this property
>   has no effect. For more info about visual templates, see the Template
>   property.

So there might be possible that `Page`'s template doesn't use `Background` property as a parameter.

---

Remove nothing from the project to change the color. Go to Common\StandardStyles.xaml. Search for "LayoutRootStyle". You will find style for `Panel`. Change `Background` there. Please note this will be affected to all the pages in the project. If you want different color for different page then you can create separate style for each page.

```xml
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't change the page background. It change the background of the grid on the page as it's that uses the LayoutRootStyle

Comment: But that's correct way to do. Changing grid's background doesn't give you expected result? What's your expected result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920397/changing-the-background-color-of-a-metro-style-app-has-no-effect

Comment: I'm trying to improve the performance of my application and I've  been looking at the OverdrawHeatMap and I'm trying to improve the elements that are overdrawing each other and one of the recommended solutions is not to have a background color on a grid. Also my app is a line of business application and it won't follow any of the standard store layouts.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to follow the default templates in that rather than setting the Background of the Page, but of the root element (usually a Grid), I'm not 100% sure why a Background on that page doesn't work (I suspect the control template).